# Number of combinations with specific rules

Tags: python, combinatorics

I would like to find out the number of combinations to the following problem:

There are 4 sections. Contained in each section are 12 categories. Each category in turn contains 3 types. A, B and C. For each section you must pick 3 types. The category can't be picked more than once and each section must have one of each type. Results might look like this:

```
S1
    C1 TA
    C2 TB
    C3 TC
S2
    C4 TA
    C5 TB
    C6 TC
S5
    C7 TA
    C8 TB
    C9 TC
S4
    C10 TA
    C11 TB
    C12 TC
```

or

```
S1
    C1 TC
    C2 TB
    C4 TA
S2
    C3 TB
    C5 TC
    C6 TA
S5
    C7 TC
    C10 TA
    C9 TB
S4
    C11 TC
    C8 TB
    C12 TA
```

I've kind of reached the end of my ability to solve this problem. I've tried loops and just filtering out the bad results but I can't really get it to work. I would love some help on this. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you post sample code of what you have already tried?

Comment: So that means... you have 4 positions for S and 12! positions for C and 3! positions for T? I derive it from the fact that order matters with no duplication. -> More like permutations of each. If so this will be a huge number.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to write a script to compute this?  It can be done purely mathematically.  My combinatorics is admittedly rather rusty, but my thinking is that this problem reduces to

```
(3! * choose(12, 3)) * (3! * choose(9, 3)) * (3! * choose(6, 3)) * (3! * choose(3, 3))
```

This simplifies nicely to simply `12!`.  You can easily generalize this too for any number of categories, sections, sections per category, and types.  I'm just uncertain why you need to write a script for this unless it's for an assignment, in which case you should really post the code you have and explain your thought process and issues.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to break the logic for this down a bit might be something like:

You need to divide the *12 categories* randomly into *4 sections*. [random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) is a good tool for this.

```
categories = range(1,13) # 1-based
# now you can use random.shuffle to shuffle it in place
import random
random.shuffle(categories) # now categories is shuffled.
# split the categories evenly between the 4 sections
sections = [categories[3*i:3*(i+1)] for i in range(4)]
```

You now need, to randomly distribute the *3 types* to the *categories* in each *section*.

```
# lets make a function that returns a randomly ordered sequence of types 1,2,3
def rand_types():
    types = [1,2,3]
    random.shuffle(types)
    return types
# now we can use this for each assignment
final = []
for section in sections:
     final.append(zip(section, rand_types()))
# [[(8, 2), (5, 1), (10, 3)], 
#  [(6, 2), (7, 3), (2, 1)], 
#  [(4, 1), (12, 3), (1, 2)], 
#  [(11, 2), (3, 1), (9, 3)]]
```

If you don't like using `zip`, you can build the `(category, type)` tuples on your own:

```
for section in sections:
    final.append([])
    for i, t in enumerate(rand_types()):
        final[-1].append((section[i], t))
```